# Indication of selected list item using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to indicate a selected list item. I need a small line under each list item when it is being selected. I tried:

```html
   <div id="types">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">item 1</a>
                    <div class="active"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">item 2</a>
                    <div></div>
                </li>      
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">item 2</a>
                    <div "></div>
                </li>   
            <li>
                    <a href="#">item 2</a>
                    <div ></div>
                </li>                                   
            </ul>
  </div>
```

In css:

```css
  .active{
    background-color: #5299bd !important;
    height: 7px;
    }
```

In jquery:

```js
    var classHighlight= 'active';

  var $thumb = $('#types ul li > a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $thumb.removeClass(classHighlight);
    $(this).addClass(classHighlight);
  });
```

Its getting highlighted on the anchor tags like, item 1 Item 2 etc.. But i need a small border like indicator/highlight, under the anchor tags, item 1, item 2..

Like this,

[image]

Please help me doing this.. Thanks

Comment: Move the class to the `li` instead, you'll have more styling options then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead

```js
$('#types ul li > a').click(function(e){
    $("#types div").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().find('div').addClass('active');
});
```

[image]

personally I think you should add a "dummy"-class, a white line, so the list-items doesnt "jump".

---

**Edit** : As  Frits van Campen comments, target `<li>` instead :

style :

```css
#types ul li {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
#types ul li.active {
    border: 1px dotted #5299bd;
}
```

markup :

```html
<div id="types">
 <ul>
     <li>
        <a href="#">item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">item 2</a>
       </li>      
       <li>
         <a href="#">item 2</a>
       </li>   
       <li>
         <a href="#">item 2</a>
       </li>                                   
   </ul>
```

script

```js
$('#types ul li > a').click(function(e){
    $("#types li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

results imho in a more "professional" look

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).addClass(classHighlight);
$(this).css('border-bottom', '8px solid cyan');
```